# difference between "Pacific standard time(mexico)" and "Pacific standard time"

Tags: c#

There are many time zones for single value of offset, is there any difference between these time zones for single value of offset.
If yes, then how to differntiate between these.
e.g. In my case I need "Pacific standard time" to be returned for offset value of "-08:00"
but I am getting "Pacific standard time(mexico)"

Comment: Many different countries may sit in approximately the same portion of the globe and tend to share the same offset. That doesn't mean that they have agreed on a single *name* for that offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not differentiate on the offset alone; you need more information. That sort of thing usually is the result of differing rules for daylight saving time in the different areas.